# How do I search through process memory for specific string filters (I already have a memory class)

Tags: vb.net, memory

I know how I can search for a specific memory address/offset, i'm just not sure how to search via a string filter and then display all memory addresses which contains the filter.

Using a program like ProcessHacker, I can select a process to read it's memory, then insert a string filter which will display all strings and memory addresses which contains that specific string. (picture example below)

Example:
`String Filter = "This is a test"`
Now anything which contains the `filter` (non case sensitive) would be displayed in a listbox along with their memory address, so if there was a string in memory which was `"dsfdsff This is a test dsfsdfsdfsd"`, that string would be displayed along with their memory address.

How would I achieve this?
Here's the memory class that i'm using: https://pastebin.com/ZC9p4B3X
(Post would be too long if I posted it here)

And here's how I can read memory segments using their memory address

[which is what i'm trying to automatically find from the specified filter]

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    mem.Setup("name") 'select process name without extension
End Sub

Private Sub BtnReadAddress_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnReadAddress.Click
    TxtBoxMemResult.Text = mem.rdString(TxtBoxMemAddress.Text) 'TxtBoxMemAddress would contain the memory address which I obtained from ProcessHacker
    'This method however only shows part of the string (if possible i'd like the full string to be displayed like in processhacker)
End Sub

End Class
```

Here's a picture of a string I searched for in Explorer.exe
https://gyazo.com/a89bf66e3ea8d737fdda83b784b09aaf

I searched for `this is the filter` and a file which was named `dfsssssssss this is the filter dsffffffffffffff` was then displayed with their memory address.

Now I can read the top result from their memory address using the memory class like this (top result was `0x29EAF0A`):

```
 mem.Setup("explorer")
 TxtBoxMemResult.Text = mem.rdString(&H29EAF0A)'Replace 0x with &H
```

Which outputted `dfsssssssss th`, some of it got cut off after a certain amount of characters.

I searched online before posting, but I could only find posts where you'd have to specifiy the memory address, which is what i'm trying to find automatically from a string filter.

If possible/if anyone's willing, I'd like it to be something like this:

```
    Dim Filter As String = "this is a test filter"
    For Each MemoryString As String In ProcessMemory

        If MemoryString.ToLower.Contains(Filter.ToLower) Then
            ListBox1.items.add(MemoryAddressLocation & " - " & MemoryString)
        End If

    Next
```

I would really appreciate it if somebody could help me achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to change the class definition. Some array's sizes are hardcoded. Here is an example, and you will have to modify the related code:

```
Public Shared Function rdString(address As Integer, size as uShort) As String
    Dim buffer As Byte() = New Byte(size ) {}
    ReadProcessMemory(ProcHandle, address, buffer, buffer.Length, 0)
    Return Encoding.Unicode.GetString(buffer).Trim
End Function
```

Comment: Yep that fixed the issue where the output would only contain parts of the string.  Any ideas for the other part of my question where I can search through the whole process memory for matching strings instead of specifying the memory address?

Comment: You may retrieve the address this way: the `Setup` function of your memory class retrieves the Process and the handle. You can access different memory addresses form a process `pProcess(0).MainModule.EntryPointAddress`, or `pProcess(0).MainModule.BaseAddress`. Let me know if that solves your problem.